# PHP Unable to assign property value by reference

Tags: php

Under what circumstances will `$foo = &$bar` not work?

I'm trying to create a wrapper class for PHP's OAuth class

```
<?php

class OAuthWrapper extends \OAuth
{
    /*
    OAuth has 3 public variables that we're inheriting
      $debug
      $debugInfo
      $sslChecks
    */

    public function __construct(\OAuth $oauth)
    {
        $oauth->enableDebug();
        $this->oauth = $oauth;
        $this->debug = &$this->oauth->debug;   // this line, it does nothing
        echo 'construct: ' . \json_encode($this->oauth->debug) . ' ' . \json_encode($this->debug) . "\n";
    }
}

$oauth new \OAuth(self::$consumerKey, self::$consumerSecret);
@oauth2 = new \OAuthWrapper($oauth);
```

## outputs

> construct: true false

I would expect true true

what gives?

Why is this->debug `false` ??

## __get and __set

I am extending a class where these properties are defined and are public.    it's not possible to redeclare the properties as protected or private.    using __get / __set is not an option.

Comment: A much better question is: why on earth are you using using references for primitive values?

Comment: Make a getter named debug and return $this->oauth->debug

Comment: Or if you want a "true" wrapper, implement the [magic `__get(str)` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) so that you can call `$myobj->debug` and have `__get` make that return `$this->oauth->debug` without anyone ever knowing that's what's happening.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans   it's the only way to ensure that setting the wrapper's public value    setts the value on the object being wrapped...    and the only way to ensure that accessing the wrappers value pulls the value from the wrapped object

Comment: No, it isn't. That's what the magic `__get` and `__set` functions are for. References for objects can make sense, but for primitives, really not.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans    I can't implement __get or __set... the properties are public.     setting them to protected or private isn't allowed

Comment: I'm confused by what you're doing.  Since you have a wrapper that derives from `OAuth`, why don't you just `$oauth = new \OAthWrapper(self::$consumerKey, self::$consumerSecret);`?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans  please double check your work (https://onlinephp.io/c/fdda1) Your magic methods are never called.   Magic getter and setters are only called on undefined or inaccessible properties

Comment: @BradKent I'm confused about the semantics here, should this class be a Wrapper (i.e. hide the Oauth object/wrap it with extra data, without altering the main object) or an extension (i.e. add/alter the behaviour of Oauth class)? If it's the first case (as I suspect), **you don't need to extend Oauth**, the oauth object could be stored in a private/protected field, , you don't set/declare `$debug` in the wrapper at all, and, as Mike said, you use magic `__get/__set`.

Comment: @user19513069  The intent was to create a "Wrapper".   The wrapper "extends" OAuth so that the wrapper will be an instanceof OAuth and can be passed to any method requiring an OAuth instance.    I have abandoned the "decorator"approach and I am now simply extending  OAuth ... no issues